# Is it Possible to Create Mac OS X installer from scratch?

Tags: macos, open-source, operating-system

I saw page when I was Searching with the key word "Open source"

http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1064/
I just want to ask whether it is possible to build a entire OS using the source code ?
and if yes then what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: An OS, yes.  OS X, no.  Only the unix underpinnings are open source; all of the stuff on top of it that makes it OS X is proprietary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. That is exactly what [Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) does to build its [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X). However, [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) is **not** [open source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) so you can not get its source code in order to build it. [Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) releases only some parts of their OS and what you can build from it is called [Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)).

Comment: thanks Mr Vlad Lazarenko for the answer :) .Any more Information that you can give me about the same

Comment: @charanraj: All the information regarding how to make an operating system from scratch, compile bootable code etc you can find on OS Dev wiki - http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Answer (score 6):

Not quite. OS X consists of many parts:

- Kernel
- UNIX commands
- GUI server and frameworks
- Standard apps

Only the kernel and a part of UNIX layer is open-sourced. If you need to have a working GUI, you need to put X server and Gnome or KDE or whatever. There used to be such a distribution, but it's no longer actively maintained.

Comment: :( humm . 
All this stuff seems so Intresting.
If I'm using windows 7 or Ubuntu 10.04 what needs to be done in order to build this Open sourced part

Comment: Google "Darwin build" or "compile xnu" or whatever. You would find many instructions. It's more difficult if you don't have a Mac, though.

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't. The OS kernel is closed-source and you can't make a working OS without a kernel.

Comment: Not quite. The kernel, called XNU, is exactly the part open-sourced!  http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.7.4/  The problem is the GUI part.

Comment: Well, technically the answer is YES, but you have to have the source code. Right? Go get it :-)

Comment: Ok thanks, I just learned something myself. Main thing is not everything required is open sourced.